# Rails/Ruby select_tag and selected not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, html-select

have a problem with rails select_tag and the selected attribute, as it does not seem to pass the selected value, only all the items to controller.

In the view is below form block,

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag 'Exportações'  %> <br/>
        <div class="input-group">
        <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(statuses.map { |status| [status, status] }, :selected => params[:status]), :multiple => true, :prompt => 'All', :class => 'form-control shadow-sm form-control-sm'%>
        <div class="input-group-append">
        <%= link_to admin_status_export_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-dark ml-4', method: :post do %>
        <%= icon('fas', 'file-excel ', ' Exportaçõ') %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And for the moment, to identify individual statuses (whitelist etc), in controller just outputting as json, after compare whats been sent to all the items in DB:

```
 def customers_status_export
@customers = Customer.where(status_trust: %w[blacklist whitelist normal])
@status = params[:status]
if @status.present?
  @customers = @customers.where(status_trust: @status)
end
render json: @customers

When one item is selected in the view (whitelist, of which 4 are in DB, and whitelist, blacklist and normal in the select box.) we still get all the items as json, when only want for now the 4 whitelist items, so the selected param in the select_tag is not catching whitelist?
```

The  statuses are mapped from an earlier call to db by uniq, in case any more are added, would it be better to hard code them in the select_tag, or is something else affecting this?

(Everything else is fine, including the csv file download at finish, which is all the items, instead of just the 4 items whitelisted, and selected)

Any tips welcome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options_for_select basically the input is an array for first parameter and second parameter is directly the value of it.

```rb
  options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard" ], "MasterCard")
  # above is an array and the second parameter is the selected value
```

for your problem

```rb
  # if statuses is an array

  options_for_select(statuses.map { |status| status }, params[:status])

  # if statuses is a record

  options_for_select(statuses.map { |status| status.put_here_field_name }, params[:status])
```

Edit 2: options_from_collection_for_select

```rb
  
  options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
  # since you want more than one selected items I think this can help
  in controller / other place
  @selected_reason_array = ['abc', 'def']

  options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons, "id", "text", selected:  @selected_reason_array)
  # pay attentions to second and third parameters
  # @reasons are your records that automatically will be looped
```

Comment: Hi yes have tried various, the actual term was changed to reasons  (being reasons for the status) current code is similar, but getting null on test render json of the one selected in view from controller. I read elsewhere on SO that we should be using options _for collections, as select_tag doesnt have a selected param, code is below, similar but a different, here reasons is an array, reason is the array item,

Comment: <%= select_tag :reason,  options_for_select(reasons.map { |reason| [reason.to_s.gsub('_', ' ').titleize, reason] }, params[:reason]), prompt: 'All', class: 'form-control shadow-sm form-control-sm'%>

Comment: I read here that the options_for_collection method should be use in this scenario, any knowledge of that with the above reasons/reason? Thanks

Comment: see my edit 2 above

Comment: Yes the controller and csv download service can handle the submissions. Ill try this and get back to check this answer, which I'm pretty sure will be close to whats needed. Thanks

Comment: Looks doable though not quite got it working yet, here:      <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons, 'reasons', 'reasons', selected: @selected_reason_array), class: 'form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm', id: 'reasons' %>    This gets problem with form style unlike the options_select, and only get the dropdown arrow, no box, its still a select_tag, so cant see why, any knowledge of this, its Bootstrap 4.3?. Not sure need the id here as no Javascript? Thanks

Comment: <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons, 'reason', 'reason.to_s.gsub('_', ' ').titleize', selected: @selected_reason_array), class: 'form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm', id: 'reasons' %>   This gets syntax error, & problem with form style unlike the options_select, and only get the dropdown arrow, no box, its still a select_tag, so cant see why

Comment: Got this but wants more arguments , given 2 wants 3-4  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons.map { |reason| [reason, reason] },  selected: @selected_reason_array), class: 'form-control form-control-sm shadow-sm', id: 'reasons' %>

Comment: Got this  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons.find(:all) "id" "name"), selected: params[:reason], class: 'form-control shadow-sm form-control-sm'%> which has the extra args, but reason has got to be an integer, its an enum, which is but comes as a string, to_i doesnt work.?

Comment: This is the @reasons array ["other_reason", "Contestation", "compliance_verified", "request_for_info", "law_proceeding", "sent_by_merchant"]

Comment: undefined method `reason' for "sent_by_merchant":String  with options_from_collection_for_select(@reasons, "id", "reason", selected:  @selected_reason_array)

Comment: If change reason to status_trust_reason get undefined method `status_trust_reason' for "Contestation":String

Comment: 2nd param, whatever it is, is undefined for the item, which is a string (from the @reasons array) got to admit, this one has got me a little!

Comment: "id", "text"  id is fine, text is not, for any item out of the @reasons array, so 2nd param cant get right.

Comment: Typical examples use the model, or object, so all the attrs are available, but here we have already pruned them down in to the @reasons array, hard to find examples of that, should we not be able to use just the options_for_select?

Comment: Have gone back to the options_select   <%= select_tag :status_trust_reason,  options_for_select(@reasons.map { |reason| [reason.to_s.gsub('_', ' ').titleize, reason] }), prompt: 'Todos', class: 'form-control shadow-sm form-control-sm'%>  as this gets and displays them in right place, only thing missing is the selected, and after that, multiple. Must be a way of doing this.

Comment: Get the array like this   @reasons = listed.map { |customer| customer.status_trust_reason }.uniq.drop(1).map { |reason| [reason.to_s.gsub('_', ' ').titleize, reason] }   which gives us this to put in the options_for_select

Comment: Changed it, nearly working so started new question.